# Training CNN for NIST digits using tiny-dnn

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, ocr, tiny-dnn

I have been trying to train a CNN using tiny-dnn library for digit recognition. The database used was NIST 19. The number of samples per class is 1000 for training and 30 for testing. So total number of samples for training is 
1000*10=10000. OpenCV is used for image processing.

The maximum accuracy obtained was 40%. Is this due to low number of samples?
How to improve the accuracy?

The code is given below

```
ConvolutionalNN::train()
{
    network<sequential> net;

    // add layers
    net << conv(32, 32, 5, 1, 6) << tiny_dnn::activation::tanh()  // in:32x32x1, 5x5conv, 6fmaps
        << ave_pool(28, 28, 6, 2) << tiny_dnn::activation::tanh() // in:28x28x6, 2x2pooling
        << fc(14 * 14 * 6, 120) << tiny_dnn::activation::tanh()   // in:14x14x6, out:120
        << fc(120, 10);                     // in:120,     out:10

    assert(net.in_data_size() == 32 * 32);
    assert(net.out_data_size() == 10);

    DatabaseReader db;
    db.readTrainingFiles();

    // hold labels -> training filenames
    std::vector<int> labels = db.getTrainLabels();
    std::vector<std::string> trainingFilenames = db.getTrainFileNames();

    std::vector<label_t> train_labels;
    std::vector<vec_t> train_images;

    // loop over training files
    for(int index=0; index<trainingFilenames.size(); index++)
    {
        // output on which file we are training
        std::cout << "Analyzing label -> file: " <<  labels[index] << "|" <<  trainingFilenames[index] << std::endl;

        // read image file (grayscale)
        cv::Mat imgMat = cv::imread(trainingFilenames[index], 0);

        Mat nonZero;
        Mat invert = 255 - imgMat;
        findNonZero(invert, nonZero);
        Rect bb = boundingRect(nonZero);
        Mat img = invert(bb);

        int w=32, h=32,scale=1;
        cv::Mat resized;
        cv::resize(img, resized, cv::Size(w, h));

        imshow("img", resized);
        waitKey(30);
        //convert to float

        resized.convertTo(resized, CV_32FC1);
        cv::normalize(resized,resized, -1, 1, NORM_MINMAX);

        //convert to vec_t

        vec_t d;
        tiny_dnn::float_t *ptr = resized.ptr<tiny_dnn::float_t>(0);
        d = tiny_dnn::vec_t(ptr, ptr + resized.cols * resized.rows );

        train_images.push_back(d);
        train_labels.push_back(labels[index]);


    }

    // declare optimization algorithm
    adagrad optimizer;

    cout << "Training Started" << endl;

    // train (50-epoch, 30-minibatch)
    net.train<mse, adagrad>(optimizer, train_images, train_labels, 30, 50);

    cout << "Training Completed" << endl;



    // save
    net.save("net");

}
```

Thanks
Amal

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to predict only 10 classes? If I remember correctly, NIST 19 has 62 classes, so you should create an output layer with softmax activation with 62 neurons. And by the way, tanh activation is way old, I suggest you to use ReLU.

You can also try to do some Data Augmentation. Try to generate random perturbations to input images as you keep training the CNN.

Comment: Just trying with numbers first. Will try with all 62 classes later. I will also try out ReLU. The problem though was with high learning rate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with high learning rate. When the learning rate was changed from the default value of 0.01 to 0.001 the accuracy increased from 40% to 90 %

The changed line was

```
optimizer.alpha = static_cast<tiny_dnn::float_t>(0.001);
```

Thanks

Amal